# Is there a way of hiding sections of a form with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms

I am trying to build a Form that is dynamic. I have the form sections built. 
In the Header of the form, there is a dropdown option, with five option's that are relevant to five sections of the form. I want to hide all sections until a dropdown option is selected, revealing the relevant section.

I'm trying to do this without Jquery, as I'm trying to grow my javascript skills

```
    <label for="issueDescInput">Date of Requests</label>
        <br>
     <input type="date" class="form-control" id="issueSeverityInput">
        <br>

        <label for="TOR">Tasks</label>
         <select class="form-control" id="issueSeverityInput">
          <option value="CO">Task 1</option>
          <option value="ASM">task 2</option>
          <option value="SM">task 3</option>
          <option value="AM">Task 4</option>
          <option value="RC">Task 5</option>
        </select>

       <div class="Tasks-section">
        <div class="Task 1">

      <p>test</p>

       </div>  
       </div>

     var select = document.getElementById('TOR'),
     onChange = function(event) {
    var shown = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == "SM";

    document.getElementById('hidden_div').style.display = shown ? 'block' 
  : 'none';
};
```

Comment: wrap each section in a div. Apply the display none to all of them and on change of the select toggle the relevant div

Comment: It's commendable that you want to grow in a positive direction (to JS away from jQ) but we require that you post the JS you have tried to use. See [mcve]

Comment: Post in the question not the comments. We need broken code to fix. To fix it we need it presented in a certain way which is described in this section:  [mcve]

Comment: Hopefully that help

Answer (score 1):

I think you can have a look at this sample using pure javascript, I already made a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/DieByMacro/pen/arKaRX):

A slightly change has been made to the HTML to make things easier.

https://codepen.io/DieByMacro/pen/arKaRX

```js
(function() {
  const selectOption = document.querySelector('#issueSeverityInput');
  const tasks = document.querySelectorAll('.task-section');
  const cssVisible = 'is-visible';
  
  // Add select onChange event handler
  selectOption.addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler );
  
  // Calling trigger to check current selected value and update at first time
  triggerSelect();
  
  function triggerSelect() {
    // Get the current selected at first load
    const currentSelect = selectOption[selectOption.selectedIndex].value
    
    // Update the task
    updateCurrentTask(currentSelect)
  }
  
  function updateCurrentTask(value) {
    // Find the correct task to update by adding/removing CSS `is-visible` class
    for(const task of tasks) {
      if (task.getAttribute('data-value') === value ) {
        task.classList.add(cssVisible)
      } else task.classList.remove(cssVisible)
    }
  }
  
  function onChangeHandler(event) {
    console.log('Selected: ', event.currentTarget.value);
    updateCurrentTask(event.currentTarget.value);
  }
})();
```

```css
/*
We init the task-section by hiding it. Then later we will use js to toggle class `is-visible` 
*/
.task-section {
  display: none;
}
.task-section.is-visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<label for="TOR">Tasks</label>
<select class="form-control" id="issueSeverityInput">
  <option value="1">Task 1</option>
  <option value="2">task 2</option>
  <option value="3">task 3</option>
  <option value="4">Task 4</option>
  <option value="5">Task 5</option>
</select>

<div class="tasks-wrapper">
  <div class="task-section" data-value="1">
    <p>This is task 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="task-section" data-value="2">
    <p>This is task 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="task-section" data-value="3">
    <p>This is task 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="task-section" data-value="4">
    <p>This is task 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="task-section" data-value="5">
    <p>This is task 5</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**JavaScript**
There a couple of issues with the present JS:

**Issue #1**
 An on-event property needs to be suffixed to an object by dot notation and must be lowercase. A comma operator just includes the declaration of `select` and then fails.

```
var select = document.getElementById('TOR'), 
onChange = function(event) {...
```

First declare a variable to reference a DOM Object, then use dot notation to bind the on-event property to the variable.

```
var select = document.getElementById('TOR');
select.onchange = function(event) {...
```

---

**Issue #2**
 I'm assuming that the next line was to assign the value of currently selected option because the next line uses it...sort of...I think. Anyways a `==` is for comparing two loosely typed values (which means that a string `"3"` can be duck-typed to a number 3). Assigning only one value out of five possibilities defeats the purpose of using a select.

```
var shown = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == "SM";
```

A select can be accessed directly to get the value of the currently selected option. The use and reuse of variables is an important and fundamental paradigm in programming. So reuse what you already have. Note a specific value is not assigned (<del>"SM"</del>) -- instead the ***value of whatever will be selected*** is assigned to `shown`.

```
var shown = select.value;
```

---

**Issue #3**
The last line is syntactically correct yet it is wrong in that it belies what the rest of the code will end as. Referencing #id is fine in of itself but having multiple tags that are similar in purpose and design should be grouped. Class and in forms name attributes should be used for groups. `document.querySelectorAll()` can be used for collecting multiple tags into groups called NodeLists or HTML Collections (slight difference between them). Being that you have a form, the following demo employs a few special Web APIs that specialize in form tags and [form controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement#Elements_that_are_considered_form_controls). Here's a list of references of what was used for the demo, details on what's happening line by line is commented in the demo:

- [**HTMLFormElement API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement#Usage_notes) - Accessing `<form>` tags.
- [**HTMLFormControlsCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection) and [**`​.elements` property**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements) - Accessing that `<form>` tags form controls.
- [**`classList` property**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) - Manipulate the class attribute.

There are a substantial amount of changes to the OP code (just about everything but basic function.) Of note is that the option values are changed to index numbers in order to facilitate efficiency and flexibility by use of generic values.

---

**Demo**

```js
// Reference the form
const main = document.forms.main;
/*
Collect all form controls into a NodeList (input, output,
textarea, select, button, fieldset) nested within form#main.
*/
const x = main.elements;
/*
A - Pass Event Object 
B - Get the value of select#TOR (e.target always points to the
    clicked, changed, hovered, etc tag) and convert it into a real
    number.
C - Collect all form controls [name=tasks] into a NodeList    
    (x.tasks).
D - Loop through the NodeList and remove .show class from each 
    tag of NodeList (fieldset[name=tasks])
E - if the value from line #B is NOT -1...
F - Assign class .show to the fieldset within the NodeList at the
    indexed position of the value from line #B
*/
function menu(e) { //A
  const selected = Number(e.target.value); //B
  const tasks = x.tasks; //C

  for (let t = 0; t < tasks.length; t++) { //D
    tasks[t].classList.remove('show'); //D
  }
  if (selected != -1) { //E
    tasks[selected].classList.add('show'); //F
  }
}

// Register select#TOR to the change event, menu() is the callback
x.TOR.onchange = menu;
```

```css
:root {
  font: 700 2.5vw/1.2 Verdana;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

section.task {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5vh 2vw;
}

fieldset.task {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 85%;
  margin: 2vh auto 5vh 1vw;
  visibility: collapse;
  transform: scaleY(0);
  transform-origin: top;
}

fieldset.task.show {
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: scaleY(1);
  transition: 0.4s transform ease-out
}

input,
output,
select,
button {
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
  height: 6vh;
  line-height: 6vh;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding: 0 3px
}

#date0 {
  height: 7vh;
  line-height: 7vh;
  width: 30vw;
}

#TOR {
  height: 8vh;
  line-height: 8vh;
}
```

```html
<form id='main'>
  <header class='menu'>
    <label for="date0">Date of Requests</label>
    <input id="date0" name='date' class="date" type="date">
    <label for="TOR">Tasks</label>
    <select id="TOR" class="menu">
      <option value='-1' selected>Choose a Task</option>
      <option value="0">Task 1</option>
      <option value="1">Task 2</option>
      <option value="2">Task 3</option>
      <option value="3">Task 4</option>
      <option value="4">Task 5</option>
    </select>
  </header>
  <section class='task'>
    <fieldset id='CO' name='tasks' class="task show">
      <legend>Task 1</legend>
      <p>CO</p>
      <p>CO</p>
      <p>CO</p>
      <p>CO</p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id='ASM' name='tasks' class="task">
      <legend>Task 2</legend>
      <p>ASM</p>
      <p>ASM</p>
      <p>ASM</p>
      <p>ASM</p>
      <p>ASM</p>
      <p>ASM</p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id='SM' name='tasks' class="task">
      <legend>Task 3</legend>
      <p>SM</p>
      <p>SM</p>
      <p>SM</p>
      <p>SM</p>
      <p>SM</p>
      <p>SM</p>
      <p>SM</p>
      <p>SM</p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id='AM' name='tasks' class="task">
      <legend>Task 4</legend>
      <p>AM</p>
      <p>AM</p>
      <p>AM</p>
      <p>AM</p>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id='RC' name='tasks' class="task">
      <legend>Task 5</legend>
      <p>RC</p>
      <p>RC</p>
      <p>RC</p>
      <p>RC</p>
      <p>RC</p>
      <p>RC</p>
      <p>RC</p>
      <p>RC</p>
      <p>RC</p>
      <p>RC</p>
      <p>RC</p>
      <p>RC</p>
      <p>RC</p>
    </fieldset>
  </section>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, everyone for your help!